# How should I save status ids?

Tags: format, chat, status, forum

I was just wondering why some people format their status ids like this:

```
-1 Offline
 0 Online
 1 Busy
 2 Away
 3 DoNotDisturb
```

Why don't they simply start at 0 or 1?

Should I use the same format? Is it some kind of standard? Are there any advantages?

Comment: The Java API uses a similar error code system for `System.exit()`.  A value of `0` means everything went normally, and any other value means there was a problem of some sort.  The chat codes you listed also seem to follow this behavior, namely `0` means that the user is online and all is normal, and the other values means that the user is in some other state.

Comment: I believe the "0 or 1" method is your best bet unless you are ABSOLUTELY certain there is no overlap.  Personally, I would separate offline and online from the other 3 statuses you list.  Where things get more complex is with the status of an account in the review process. Accounts can be (1) under review; (2) active; (3) banned; (4) deleted.  Accounts can belong to (1) normal users; (2) moderators; (3) admins... so there are many aspects to an account's "status".